# Handling carriage return/line feed in MATLAB GUI user controls

Tags: matlab, text, user-controls, newline, carriage-return

I have a MATLAB program I am developing in order to do some image processing stuff and need to use a user control into a `MATLAB GUI` user interface I created ad-hoc.

This user control is a `List Box` and there I would like to insert some text. Well the problem is not that I cannot put text there, I can do that using this call:

```
set(handles.mylistbox, 'String', 'MyStringToPrint');
```

Well the problem is that this call does not let me insert many lines in my list box but just overwrite the previous one.

I wish to find a way to let my code insert the new text in a new line. This should not be so difficult to do and it is also a simple pattern:

```
texttoprint = 'My text to add'
oldtext = get(handles.MyListBox, 'String') %Holding the previous text here
set(handles.MyListBox, 'String', [oldtext '\n' texttoprint]) %Setting (no line feed printed)
set(handles.MyListBox, 'String', [oldtext char(10) texttoprint]) %Setting (this fails too)
```

Well it is ok and it does not raise any error BUT, `\n` DOES NOT WORK.
I do not have any new line... BUT NEED TO!!!!

How should I solve this?
The problem is that I need to print text in this user control, not on the MATLAB commandline (that is very simple just by doing `sprintf()`).

What to do? Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a listbox, set the string property to a cell

```
set(myListboxHandle,'String',{'myFirstLine';'mySecondLine'})
```

If you want to add another line, call

```
contents = get(myListboxHandle,'String');
set(myListboxHandle,[contents;{'another line'}])
```

For multiline text in GUIs otherwise, use `char(10)` instead of `\n`, i.e.

```
set(someUiControlHandle,'String',sprintf('my first line%smy second line',char(10)))
```

Comment: thankyou but I need to add lines parametrically. I do not know how many lines there are... You make me an example basing on the fact of having two lines, but what about I do not know how many they are??? Furthermore, sprintf is for commandline output, it is no use for me here... :( Maybe I'm misunderstanding something... please tell me if I am correct.

Comment: @Andry: I have added an additional example.

Answer (score 0):

When working with list boxes it's usually easier to deal with the options as a [cell array of strings](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/strings.html). So, you would initialize your list box as follows:

```
set(handles.MyListBox,'String',{'Option 1'});
```

And then you can add options to your list box like so:

```
newOption = 'Option 2';
oldOptions = get(handles.MyListBox,'String');
set(handles.MyListBox,'String',[oldOptions; {newOption}]);
```